Action Script 3 - Add new frame to MovieClip from code?
Some of my classes are generated from code. Now I have ideas to refactor them, but I need 2 frames.
Looks like the only way now is to re-create them in Adobe Animate with 2 frames.
Maybe I've missed some workaround or framework to add new frame to MovieClip?

Use an array of Sprites instead of a MovieClip timeline. Timelines are poorly documented, while the display list is both simpler and easier to understand, code and reuse. If you're using a set of "just" images, use a list of BitmapDatas and wrapping Bitmaps instead for performance (provided you don't scale anything, or the scale is a power of 2).
